# Need to Create in-memory file structure hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, jakarta-ee

I need to write a Java program which reads data from a file called input.txt, parses it, and figures out the total size of storage consumed by each directory in this system.

The size of storage consumed by any directory is defined as the sum of the size of this directory, sizes of all the files in this directory and the total storage sizes consumed by all the directories in this directory. The program should write the name of each directory, and the total storage consumed by it to a file called output.txt.

Consider the following input file:

```
Name        | Type      | Size       | Owner | Directory

root        , directory , 128        , admin , NONE

users       , directory , 512        , admin , root

navin       , directory , 1024       , navin , users

navin.jpg   , photo     , 128000     , navin , navin
```

This contains information about files stored in a file system. Each line corresponds to one file, and the fields are separated by commas. "The first field contains the filename, the second contains the file type, the third field is the size of the file in bytes, the fourth field is the username of the owner of the file, and the last field is the name of the parent directory of this file" (i.e. the name of the directory in which this file is located.) Note: the special parent directory name NONE indicates that this file is the root directory of the filesystem.

Also, for the purposes of this program, assume that all file/directory names are unique in the system.

I have tried below code:

```
package com.threads;

import java.io.*;

public class TotalDirectorySize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Row values from file" + " " + sCurrentLine);
                String[] values = sCurrentLine.split(",");
                for (String val : values)
                    System.out.println("Values are" + " " + val);
                createDirectory(values);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here I am trying to fetch five values in an array and want to create specific directory based on the last value in array. I am thinking of creating an in-memory structure but not sure how to use data structures java. Please suggest a good method to do it.

Comment: Create a dedicated object for your data (with 5 fields: name, type, size, owner and directory)

Comment: The answer I just posted on a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26773307/616460) should serve as a good example here as well.

Comment: There was a very similar question a few days ago (someone from the same school probably)